# Sugar CRM - how to set same home page automatically for group of users?

Tags: sugarcrm

my customer uses 6.5 version.
They will have 50 users. All will have same home page. Is it possibel to create one home page manually and then to set that page autamtically for all other users or not? It will be very painful if we had to create for each user same home page. Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use this perfect module for that:

- http://www.sugarforge.org/projects/dashboardmanage/
- http://www.sugarforge.org/news/post.php?forum_id=6297

Comment: Hello, thanks for response it looks good. I want to try it. I am sorry for asking this but this is my first Sugar project I just started to work with it-can you explain me in couple of words what is the procedure for installing this (or any other) plugin? Sorry for this I know it is probabbly easy question for you but I do not know. Thanks in advance,

Comment: is it just using module builder and Deploy action or something else?

Comment: can you help me with this question?

Comment: Go to Admin and use the Module Loader to load modules. From there you can upload the module and install.